# How to use outer link?

Tags: link

I'd like to open other website page using outer link.

For example, when I write a code like this google
it doesn't work. Just 404 page opened.

If I open google page, do I have to use another code?

Comment: can please describe properly

Comment: `<a href="http://google.com">google</a>` add link with `http://`

Comment: Thanks. I think I forgot 'http://' code, I solved it for your advice.